# Разный размер шрифта на разных страницах

Tags: css

Проблема такая: при одном и том же подключеном файле css на разных страницах размер шрифта в меню меняется:

- [нормально отображается](http://vilkovo.pp.ua),
- [неправильно отображается](http://vilkovo.pp.ua/index.php?mid=2&pid=22).

не могу понять, в чём проблема.

Comment: Кстати, правильно будет слово "проект", а не "проэкт".

Comment: посмотрите как это проблему решили на сайте [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru).

Comment: спасибо за урок русского языка, но мне скорее нужен был урок языка css

Comment: @Noise Не с глаголами всегда пишется отдельно, ть пишется только в неопределенной форме глагола.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается вашей проблемы, определите стили для таблиц, так как в одном случае (не хочу копаться, хочу спать) ваша таблица отгребает предопределенные стили у браузера, тем самым, как мне кажется, перекрывая `font-size: 75%;`, а во втором все работает отлично. Чтобы удостовериться добавьте атрибут к таблице `style="font-size:75%;` (к какой, подскажет мой UPD ниже)

**UPD**

Например, в Опере, вы легко можете нажать на любом элементе правой клавишей мыши и... "проинспектировать элемент". Похожее есть и в других браузерах.

Comment: спасибо, помогло